# Finding volume of the given right tetrahedron by integration

Tags: integration

> Find the volume of the given right tetrahedron

[image]

The cross section area of for this diagram is a right angled triangle.

Using similar triangles: $\frac{b}{h} = \frac{48}{140} = \frac{12}{35}$

Therefore, $h= \frac{35}{12} b$

The equation of line through the points $(148,0)$, and $(0,48)$ is $y= \frac{-12}{37} + 48$ and since $y$ correspond to the base of the cross sectional area. The length of the base is $\frac{-12}{37} + 48$

Then, $h = \frac{35}{12} ( \frac{-12}{37} + 48) = \frac{-35}{37} x + 140$

From here, how do I find the area of the cross section area? I know that it is $A(x) = \frac{1}{2} b h$

How do I get $A(x) = \frac{210}{1369} x^2 - \frac{1680}{37} x + 3360$ ?

Im stuck at finding the correct answer for the area above before I can integrate to find volume

Comment: The area of the "base" triangle at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ is $ \ \frac12·48·140 \ = \  3360 \ \ $ and each  cross-sectional triangle along the $ \ x-$direction is similar.  The areas of the similar triangles are related by a scale factor $ \ \lambda^2 \ $ with $ \ \lambda \ $ changing linearly from $ \ 1 \ $ to $ \ 0 \ $ as $ \ x \ $ changes from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ 148 \ \ . \ $ (Incidentally, when you do the volume integration, you can then just integrate $ \ 3360·[\lambda(x)]^2 \ \ $ by multiplying out the polynomial or by a $ \ u-$substitution.)

Comment: By your approach, you are nearly there.  You established that $ \ b \ = \ \frac{12}{35}·h \ \ , \ $ so $ \ b(x) \ = \ -\frac{12}{37}x + 48 \ \ . \ $ Then $$ A(x) \ = \ \frac12·h(x)·b(x) \ \ = \ \ \frac12·\left(-\frac{35}{37}x + 140 \right)· \left(-\frac{12}{37}x + 48 \right) \ \ $$ gives you the polynomial you've written.